# Opening Specific Data Within App in Flutter with QR Code

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

For example, if I have a Flutter app that just scans the QR code from somewhere, can it open up, for example, a specific user within the app, with database pulled from Firestore?

**Could that work within the app itself, or would I have to use, for example, Flutter Web, or some other framework (just regular HTML, CSS, JS)?**

Let me know if the question isn't clear, I will explain it as best as I can if it isn't. To summarize; Have a Flutter app that scans the QR code on opening, then redirecting the user to specific database from Firestore **(name: 'name', images: ['that user images'])** etc. Or would you need to use any other framework to actually open a link from a website?

Comment: you don't need to use webfeed or anything else to open a website by scaning qr code. Here is my code You can check it out https://github.com/timurturbil/Scaning-Qr-Code-with-Flutter

Comment: I might have not explained properly. I know that you can open any link with qr scanner, but I was wondering if it was possible to open a particular user id in the app itself when scanned.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand, let me know if I'm missing something.

1. You open the app and you have a qr scanner
2. You scan a qr code (the qr code have for example a user ID).
3. Once you read the ID, you look for it making a call to firebase.
4. Last, you display the info associate with the ID in firebase (user name, user image).

You can do all this using Flutter + Firebase.

Comment: It was just my train of thought, since I never done anything like it. It's an example, the main app page would be qr code scanner, which when scanned would lead to particular user id (and their particular page) from Firebase.

Comment: I am looking for this resolution too. I've tried accessing a Firestore Document in Angular via a generated QR code using parameters: https://<Site Root>/events/document/<docId>, but it fails with a 404 error.

Is it possible to deep link a QR Code to a location in a Flutter app with the docId variable?